# Aggregate initialization for structs + initializer_list: new vs static

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2017

Recently I have debugged strange issue appeared as result of allocation objects of some complex structs (constructor is not defined). As result I detected that if I have, for example:

```
struct A {
   int                           b;
   std::initializer_list<Type*>  c;
};
```

then objects a of this `struct A` allocated using `new` and statically are different:

`A a {1, {new Type(), new Type()}};`
does what I wanted, but

`A* a = new A {1, {new Type(), new Type()}};`
performs some buggy initialization of `c` member.

Are these cases different by C++ standard, compiler's bad behavior or my mistake? Tested on VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

If you would read the documentation, you could avoid such problems: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list.

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

So as suggested in the link in comments, you should store data in a permanent container (here an `std::vector` would probably be the proper choice).